# Como inserir um id no SQLITE android?

Tags: android, sqlite

estou tentando inserir o mesmo id que recebo do banco do servidor no banco do android através do sqlite, porem, ele esta gerando um id próprio, estou usando o auto increment na primary key, já tentei usar unique e já tentei não declarar ninguém como primary key, porem da erro ao tentar inserir no banco do celular, só funciona quando ponho primary key, porem gera o autoincrement que não preciso

Comment: Seria mais prático e mais seguro ter uma coluna separada, por exemplo id_server para guardar o id original. Querendo ou não, o SQLite vai precisar de um índice próprio mesmo. Você até pode não declarar primary key, mas de qualquer forma internamente o SQLite vai ter uma coluna primária.

Comment: eu tambem pensei nisso, mas tava tentando nao fazer dessa forma

Comment: Declarar ou não uma coluna primária no SQLite só muda o fato do ID interno ser associado a uma coluna com "nome próprio" ou não. Se quiser mesmo não ter a chave primária "padrão", tem que definir `WITHOUT ROWID` na hora de criar a tabela, mas aí precisa definir uma PK própria sua obrigatoriamente. O `AUTOINCREMENT` você pode omitir na criação da tabela, independente de ter ou não PK definida (até para economizar um pouco de recursos).

Comment: vou fazer dessa forma mesmo entao, se alguem aparecer com outra solução melhor... kkk

Comment: Não entendo o que poderia ter de melhor, para o que vc está pedindo. Basicamente o WITHOUT ROWID + sua própria PK deve resolver os seus indices próprios. E eu sinceramente acho que o que você quer fazer na verdade não é melhor do que deixar o DB ter chave própria, mas aí só você que está projetando a aplicação que realmente sabe o que é melhor para o seu caso.

Comment: é que eu precisava manter um trecho do banco do servidor, replicado exatamente igual no android, pq depois o projeto vai seguir adiante, entao pra não haver problemas para manutenção eu tava tentando nao usar mais uma coluna, mas acredito que a sua solução não é ruim não ;D